# How do you make a bin directory

Tags: directory, bin-folder

How do I make a bin directory in the terminal

Comment: Linux? Windows?

Comment: Give more information, please. Are you talking about bin in the root or what? The answer is ‘mkdir bin’.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean you want to create a directory **FROM** the terminal, and in a Linux based system, then open your terminal and type in the following -

`mkdir your_directory_name`

as simple as this. You have options with `mkdir`.

You should really check out the man page for the mkdir (or any command for that matter). All you have to do is `man mkdir`.